# Sum of field with where condition of this field - Influxdb

Tags: sum, influxdb, influxql

I want to get the sum of `result_code` where `result_code=0`.

What I found is that querying without sum gives me result but adding the aggregation sum() and then I have 0 as a result.

For those who want an understanding of the use case :
I use telegraf to ping some internal IP address to check it's availability (pings every 10s with a timeout of 5s) and I want to get its uptime (`result_code=0`) per day.

I have tried changing the field in the sum function but that doesn't work better.

```
SELECT sum("result_code") FROM "ping" WHERE ("url" = 'MyUrl') AND time >= 1557957600000ms and result_code=0

name: ping
time                sum
----                ---
1557957600000000000 0
```

```
name: ping
time                result_code
----                -----------
1557988031000000000 0
1557988040000000000 0
...
```

In my example I expect to have

```
name: ping
time                sum
----                ---
1557957600000000000 2
```

Comment: Sum of zeroes is zero - what are you expecting to get? Looks like you need `count(result_code)` -  not `sum()`. Also,  you're using aggregating function without `group by time(1d)` in query.

Comment: I meant `count` instead of `sum` thanks for pointing that out
P.S. : using `group by time(1d)` gives me 2 rows (might be a problem with timezones...)

Comment: To correct the timezone issue I used : `GROUP BY time(1d) , deviceId TZ('Europe/Paris')`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `COUNT`, rather than the `SUM` of a collection of zero values.